# What is the difference between DispatchIndirect and Dispatch?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

What is the difference between `Dispatch` and `DispatchIndirect` of Unity?

I tried to know that many times, but it's failed.

I thought `DispatchIndirect` would cause shaders to run multiple times at once.

But that wasn't true. I really don't know now.

ps. The code below is not working right now.

```
#pragma kernel CSMain

struct IndirectData
{
   uint numGroupX;
   uint numGroupY;
   uint numGroupZ;
   uint texIndex;
};

RWTexture2D<float4> renderTexture;
StructuredBuffer<Texture2D> texBuffer;
StructuredBuffer<IndirectData> dispatchData;

[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void CSMain(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
   // some code...

   IndirectData data = dispatchData[**ShaderIndex**];  //I wanted this index value...
   renderTexture[id.xy] = texBuffer[data.texIndex];

   // some code...
}
```

C# Code

```
// some code...

struct IndirectData
{
   public uint numGroupX;
   public uint numGroupY;
   public uint numGroupZ;
   public uint texIndex;
   // some code...
};

// some code...

IndirectData[] data = new IndirectData[orderCount];
void SomeFunc(out data);

// some code...

ComputeBuffer buffer = new ComputeBuffer(orderCount, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IndirectData)), ComputeBufferType.IndirectArguments);
buffer.SetData(data);
    
shader.SetBuffer(kernelID, rectID, buffer);
shader.DispatchIndirect(kernelID, buffer, 0);

// some code...
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title, from my experience, the following `ID3D11DeviceContext::Dispatch` call,

```
context->Dispatch(x, y, z);
```

is equivalent to calling `DispatchIndirect` with a buffer with `{x,y,z}` as its contents (same as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72214160/gpu-what-are-the-proper-thread-dimensions-for-a-compute-shader-with-a-very-large/72214294#72214294)):

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc{};
desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(unsigned) * 3;
desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_DRAWINDIRECT_ARGS;

unsigned dim[] = { x, y, z };
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA argdata{};
argdata.pSysMem = dim;

ID3D11Buffer* argbuf;
device->CreateBuffer(&desc, &argdata, &argbuf);

context->DispatchIndirect(argbuf, 0);
```